# mongodb change field type to int32

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I for some reason have some fields as string and others as Int32.

I need to run a command that makes sure that all documents inside the collection are Int32 when it comes to

- season
- episode_no

I am wondering how I would go about doing that.

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5d5ea5bbbbe890f60ccbe7b8"
    },
    "show_id": {
        "$oid": "5d54fca24456f4ee892395b1"
    },
    "show_b": "rantshow",
    "season": 1,
    "episode_no": 1,
    "title": "Donald Trump and Guns.",
    "summary": "Gun laws from Australia to USA including a look at Phillipines gun control laws",
    "description": "In this part 1 of 3, we talk about US president Donald Trump and the latest gun related shootings in the US. Kevin talks about the Philippines and there gun laws and how similar they are from the US",
    "link": "https://rant.show/2019/08/gun-control-part-1/",
    "enclosureurl": "example.com/rantshow/season1/S01EP01-Part-1.mp3",
    "enclosurebyts": 56780000,
    "pubDate": {
        "$date": "2019-08-15T22:44:46.201Z"
    },
    "author": "Radio Media PTY LTD",
    "duration": "00:44:18",
    "explicit": "yes"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do following in an aggregation pipeline:

1. use `$convert` to turn the 2 fields into `int` (which is 32 bit integer)
2. `$merge` back to the original collection

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "season": {
        "$convert": {
          "input": "$season",
          "to": "int",
          //"onError": "expression",
          //"onNull": "expression"
          }
        },
        "episode_no": {
          "$convert": {
            "input": "$episode_no",
            "to": "int",
            //"onError": "expression",
            //"onNull": "expression"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "$merge": {
          "into": "collection",
          "on": "_id",
          "whenMatched": "replace"
        }
      }
    ])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iXfAr0Q0i8g) for your reference.